# Cannot find package math/bits

Tags: go

I'm getting the following error when I execute my tests. This was working previously. Not sure what I need to do in order to fix this error.

```
golang.org/x/crypto/ripemd160/ripemd160block.go:12:2: cannot find package "math/bits" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.8/1.8.7/libexec/src/math/bits (from $GOROOT)
```

Comment: `math/bits` was added in go1.9, though you should be using go1.10

Comment: This was previously working with my code in go 1.8.7 Is there a way I can get this working with 1.8.7 since swapping go version is not an option atm?

Comment: The current version of `golang.org/x/crypto` expects the current version of Go. Either update Go, or vendor an older commit of `golang.org/x/crypto`

Comment: How can I use an old commit of the library if I know the commit version if it’s a golang package not git? @JimB

Comment: What do you mean "it’s a golang package not git"? The `golang.org/x/`  packages are all pulled using git. You should be using some sort of tooling to manage your dependencies, and you would use the tool of your choice (govendor, dep, glide, etc.) to "vendor" the desired package version.

Answer (score 11):

> [Go 1.9 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9)
>
> [New bit manipulation package](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#math-bits)
>
> Go 1.9 includes a new package, math/bits, with optimized
>   implementations for manipulating bits. On most architectures,
>   functions in this package are additionally recognized by the compiler
>   and treated as intrinsics for additional performance.

You need Go version 1.9 or later.

---

I have several versions of Go installed from source in my `$HOME` directory: `~/go1.4`, `~/go1.8`, `~/go1.9`, `~/go1.10`, and `~/go` (devel). Copy the `src/math/bits` folder from go1.9 or later to go1.8. From `go1.8/src` run `go1.8 install -v math/bits`.

`go1.8`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# $HOME/bin/go1.8

export GOARCH=amd64
export GOOS=linux
export GOROOT=$HOME/go1.8 
export GOBIN=$GOROOT/bin

exec $GOBIN/go "$@"
```

Output:

```
$ cd ~/go1.8/src
$ go1.8 install -v math/bits 
math/bits
```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/bits"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(bits.UintSize)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go1.8 run bits.go
64
```

Comment: I need to use it with go 1.8.7. Is there a possibility of doing that? This was working with the same go version earlier.

Comment: Yes. See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm actually on Mac. My terminal gets closed when I execute "exec $GOBIN/go "$@" command. Is there a straight forward way to get a specific version of "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"?

Comment: @Pubudu: that's what happens if you use `exec` from the any unix command line. The example was a shell script, if you want to run the commands individually, don't use `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy package "math/bits" for you gopath.
An way is:

1. download golang 1.10+
2. make directory `<goprojectpath>/src/math`
3. copy `(cp -r ...)` from `<goroot_1.10+>/src/math/bits` to `<goprojectpath>/src/math`
4. try again: `govendor add +external`

Or install new golang version to 1.10+.